# Recursive C++ code goes into infinite loop

Tags: c++, recursion

Why does the following code go into an infinite loop:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void printarray(int arr[], int n, int i);

int main(){
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    printarray(arr,n,0);
    return 0;
}

void printarray(int arr[], int n, int i){
    if(i >=n)
        return;
    cout<<arr[i]<<"\t";
    return printarray(arr,n,i++);    //Replacing i++ by i+1 works fine
}
```

However, if I use i+1 instead of i++, the code works fine.As per my understanding i++ is effectively the same as i+1. Then what is the problem here?

Comment: `As per my understanding i++ is effectively the same as i+1` What would make you think so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i++` means "increment `i` **after** the comand finishes"

So you call the recursive function with always the same `i`. Only when the function returns `i`is incremented.

To achieve your goal use `++i` instead.

Or better, as @dxiv pointed out, `i+1`

Comment: Or just plain `i + 1`. The calling function returns right after the recursive call, so there is no real purpose to increment `i` at that point.

Comment: @dxiv You're absolutely right.

Comment: @dxiv Got it now. I was quite silly. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put `++i` instead of `i++`